# restrict the user to enter more than max value

Tags: html, angularjs

I am using input number type. How do I restrict the user to enter the number more than 100. for Example:

```
<input type="number" max=100 min=0/>
```

I have used max and min property to avoid the number is more than 100. If I use the up and down arrow the input min and max property will work correctly. Instead of Up and Down arrow, If I type the number with the help of keyboard means it is not working. i.e, It is allowing to enter more number

> like 101, 101222, 1023233434353

I want to prevent the user to enter the number if max=100. kindly help.

Thanks in advance

Comment: When user enters number beyond the range, it will throw error while submitting the form

Answer (score 1):

You can only restrict the user by putting a watch on the input and reducing the number to the closest maximum value every time the user enters anything that is more than the max value.

That said, I would not recommend doing that because that will not leave the users puzzled and confused for they will never know the max value.

I make sure the users can only input numbers by pairing the number input type with a pattern validator. Even if you the user manually types anything then pattern validation should kick in otherwise the max min validation is always there.

Have a look at the code below.

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('ctrl', function($scope) {});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.css" />

<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <div class="col-lg-12">

    <form name="fieldForm" id="fieldForm" class="customform" novalidate="">
      <div class="form-group is-empty">
        <input class="form-control" name="maxLength" id="maxLength" placeholder="Maximum Length" type="number" data-ng-model="newField.MaxLength" style="cursor: auto;" ng-min="100" ng-max="100000" ng-pattern="/^\d+$/" required>
        <span class="error-block has-error" ng-show="fieldForm.maxLength.$error.required && (fieldForm.maxLength.$dirty || fieldForm.maxLength.$touched)">
                            Max Length is required
                        </span>
        <span class="error-block has-error" ng-show="fieldForm.maxLength.$error.pattern && (fieldForm.maxLength.$dirty || fieldForm.maxLength.$touched)">
                            Only numbers allowed
                        </span>
        <span class="error-block has-error" ng-show="fieldForm.maxLength.$error.min">
                            Minimum is 100
                        </span>
        <span class="error-block has-error" ng-show="fieldForm.maxLength.$error.min">
                            Maximum is 10000
                        </span>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: I don't want to show error message. Instead of while typing manually I need to prevent to type the number, if the number is exceed the max value

Comment: this code is allowing to type manually, If I use the up and down arrow it would work properly, But I want to enter manually means that time I need to "prevent to type" the user if max length is exceed

Answer (score 0):

use ng-keydown

```
<input ng-keydown="validationFunction()" type="number>
```

In validation function you can check for the value and clear the input until the given value in within the range.